# При клике на элемент на сайте задать display: none другому элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

```
$(document).on('click', '#account', () => {
   $('main').css({
    'display': `none`
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Ну а что у тебя не работает по клику на элемент с id account скрывает тег main...

Comment: Он не скрывает main при клике не задаёт display none

Comment: Если вы ищете элемент по id, то должно быть $('#main')

Comment: нет сам тег main

Comment: У Вас либо в приведенном примере ошибка, либо прямо в коде - `none` у Вас в апострофах вместо одинарных кавычек. И чем Вас не устроил стандартный `.hide()`? Он делает тоже самое, что и Ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать даже без Jquery, вот пример кода:

`btn.addEventListener("click", function( item.style.display = 'none'; ));`

btn = Кнопка на которую нажимает пользователь для изменение блока или элемента

item = Элемнт который должен изменится

элементы получаешь через `document.getElementById(id); document.getElementsByClassName("class");`

Comment: Спасибо все ваши методы помогли спасибо что вы есть пусть у вас всегда все будет хорошо